# Allow Cross Domain AJAX in WebKit WebView

Tags: objective-c, ajax, macos, cross-domain

I am loading a local webpage in a WebView in my application. Is there a way to enable cross domain AJAX in the webview? There isn't really a point in the security feature if I have control of the code trying to do the request...

Alternatively, is there a way to pass a large amount of data into the we

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like WebView will automatically allow cross domain AJAX with local files.